# Where to insert wirisplugins.js in joomla tinymce editor

Tags: javascript, joomla, tinymce

I'm trying to use wiris plugin for tinymce in joomla.
In   http://www.wiris.com/plugins/docs/joomla  in step 5, I should insert the wirisplugins.js
Would you please specify where to put the following line ?

script src="your-plugin/integration/WIRISplugins.js?viewer=image">/script>

Answer (score 0):

In Joomla you need to include WIRISplugins.js in your template file. This file is located at `/templates/<your-template-name>/index.php`. You need to include WIRISplugins.js script before the head closing tag `</head>`.

We have included this as a note on step 5 in our Joomla installation instructions.

Comment: I have done it, but no success, yet.
For example square root symbol, does show correctly in editing window, but a broken image icon appears in test -> preview.

Comment: The problem shows itself in this test
http://<yourdomain.com>/<path_to_tinymce_installation>/plugins/tiny_mce_wiris/test.php

The other test
http://<yourdomain.com>/<path_to_tinymce_installation>/plugins/tiny_mce_wiris/integration/test.php
show ok for everything

Comment: For the first case see
[link](http://hiveschool.net/media/editors/tinymce/plugins/tiny_mce_wiris/test.php)
and
For the second case see
[link](http://hiveschool.net/media/editors/tinymce/plugins/tiny_mce_wiris/integration/test.php)

Comment: In your first link when you click on "Preview" we can see a Forbidden 403 error in our browser console log. You would need to check that with your server provider sending them the createimage request details.

Comment: If it is an access problem from the server, why it shows correctly in edit box (exampleForm), but broken in (previewBox) ?

Comment: The request we make on the edit view is a POST request, however, the request on the preview box is a GET request which we believe your server forbids probably because of the MathML characters being sent. We will convert this request to POST in our next WIRIS plugin release. We will post here again as soon as this change is included. In the meantime, you can edit `/<plugin-path>/integration/WIRISplugins.js` and change `data.length < 2000` for `false`

Comment: Thank you for prompt reply.